# Long running SQL query filling up tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

A stored procedure I am running is failing when it fills up the tempdb (32GB). It fails after around 1 hour.

The stored procedure is below:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Reporting].[Merge_Fact_Customer_Engagement]    Script Date: 23/08/2019 14:32:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER   PROCEDURE [Reporting].[Merge_Fact_Customer_Engagement]
AS


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustEng_stg') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CustEng_stg;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustEng_delta') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CustEng_delta;                                                                                      


SELECT

-- Business Key                                                                                                 
    [Customer_Engagement_Id]        

-- Foreign Keys                                         
    ,cec.[Customer_Engagement_Context_Key]                                                  -- Engagement_Type_Id                               
    ,d.[Date_Key]                           AS [Engagement_Date_Key]                        -- Engagement_Date                                  
    ,t.[TimeKey]                            AS [Engagement_Time_Key]                        -- Engagement_Time                                  
    ,c.[Contact_Key]                                                                        -- LBS_Number                                       
    ,age.[Age_Key]                          AS [Age_On_Engagement_Key]                      -- Age_On_Engagement                                
    ,pic.[Programme_Interest_Context_Key]                                                   -- Programme_Interest_Status_Code                   
    ,cnt1.[Country_Key]                     AS [Country_Of_Nationality_Key]                 -- Country_Of_Nationality_Id                        
    ,cnt2.[Country_Key]                     AS [Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Key]          -- Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Id             
    ,cnt3.[Country_Key]                     AS [Country_Of_Residency_Key]                   -- Country_Of_Residency_Id                          
    ,cnt4.[Country_Key]                     AS [Country_Lived_In_Key]                       -- Country_Lived_In_Id                              
    ,cnt5.[Country_Key]                     AS [Event_Country_Key]                          -- Event_Country_Id                             
    ,pt.[Programme_Type_Key]                                                                -- Programme_Type_Code                              
    ,p.[Programme_Key]                                                                      -- Programme_Code                                   
    ,camp1.[Campaign_Key]                   AS [Marketing_Campaign_Key]                     -- Marketing_Campaign_Id                            
    ,camp2.[Campaign_Key]                   AS [List_Load_Campaign_Key]                     -- List_Load_Campaign_Id                            
    ,camp3.[Campaign_Key]                   AS [Event_Campaign_Key]                         -- Event_Campaign_Id                                
    ,camp4.[Campaign_Key]                   AS [Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Key]             -- Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Id                    
    ,d2.[Date_Key]                          AS [Score_Removed_Date_Key]                     -- Score_Removed_Date       
    ,a.[Account_Key]                                                                        -- Account_Id       

-- Metrics
    ,ce.[Programme_Interest_Score]                                      
    ,ce.[Customer_Engagement_Score]                                 
    ,ce.[Customer_Engagement_Default_Score]                         
    ,ce.[Multi_Campaign_Attribution_Flag]                                                                   
    ,ce.[New_Contact_Flag]                                                                      
    ,ce.[Customer_Engagement_Count]                                                                 
    ,ce.[Entity_Record_Source]                                                                                          



    ,CONVERT(BIGINT, HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONCAT(
                                            [Customer_Engagement_Id] ,cec.[Customer_Engagement_Context_Key] ,d.[Date_Key] ,t.[TimeKey] ,c.[Contact_Key],age.[Age_Key],pic.[Programme_Interest_Context_Key] ,cnt1.[Country_Key] ,cnt2.[Country_Key] ,cnt3.[Country_Key] ,cnt4.[Country_Key] ,cnt5.[Country_Key] ,pt.[Programme_Type_Key] ,p.[Programme_Key] ,camp1.[Campaign_Key] ,camp2.[Campaign_Key] ,camp3.[Campaign_Key] ,camp4.[Campaign_Key] ,d2.[Date_Key] ,a.[Account_Key] ,ce.[Programme_Interest_Score] ,ce.[Customer_Engagement_Score] ,ce.[Customer_Engagement_Default_Score] ,ce.[Multi_Campaign_Attribution_Flag] ,ce.[New_Contact_Flag] ,ce.[Customer_Engagement_Count] ,ce.[Entity_Record_Source] --,[Age_On_Engagement_Key]

    ))) AS HashId


INTO   #CustEng_stg
FROM   [Integration].[Customer_Engagement] ce

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Contact] c
    ON ce.[LBS_Number] = c.[LBS_Number]
    AND CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,[Engagement_Date])) BETWEEN c.[Row_Effective_Date] AND c.[Row_Expiry_Date]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Customer_Engagement_Context] cec
    ON ce.[Engagement_Type_Id] = cec.[Engagement_Type_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Programme_Interest_Context] pic
    ON ce.[Programme_Interest_Status_Code] = pic.[Programme_Interest_Status_Code]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Campaign] camp1
    ON ce.[Marketing_Campaign_Id] = camp1.[Campaign_Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Campaign] camp2
    ON ce.[List_Load_Campaign_Id] = camp2.[Campaign_Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Campaign] camp3
    ON ce.[Event_Country_Id] = camp3.[Campaign_Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Campaign] camp4
    ON ce.[Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Id] = camp4.[Campaign_Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Programme] p
    ON ce.[Programme_Code] = p.[Programme_Code]
    AND CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,[Engagement_Date])) BETWEEN p.[Row_Effective_Date] AND p.[Row_Expiry_Date]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Programme_Type] pt
    ON ce.[Programme_Type_Code] = pt.[Programme_Type_Code]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Account] a
    ON ce.[Account_Id] = a.[Account_Id]
    AND CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,[Engagement_Date])) BETWEEN a.[Row_Effective_Date] AND a.[Row_Expiry_Date]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[DimDate] d
    ON ce.[Engagement_Date] = d.[Date_Key]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[DimDate] d2
    ON ce.[Score_Removed_Date] = d.[Date_Key]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[DimTime] t
    ON ce.[Engagement_Time] = t.[TimeKey]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Country] cnt1                                      
    ON ce.[Country_Of_Nationality_Id] = cnt1.[Country_Id]                                   

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Country] cnt2                                              
    ON ce.[Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Id] = cnt2.[Country_Id]                                                    

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Country] cnt3
    ON ce.[Country_Of_Residency_Id] = cnt3.[Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Country] cnt4
    ON ce.[Country_Lived_In_Id] = cnt4.[Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Country] cnt5
    ON ce.[Event_Country_Id] = cnt5.[Country_Id]

LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Age] age
    ON ce.[Age_On_Engagement] = age.[Age]

SELECT *
INTO   #CustEng_delta
FROM   #CustEng_stg AS s
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM   [Reporting].[Fact_Customer_Engagement] AS a
                    WHERE  a.HashId = s.HashId);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustEng_stg') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CustEng_stg;

MERGE INTO Reporting.Fact_Customer_Engagement AS T

USING #CustEng_delta AS S ON (S.[Customer_Engagement_Id] = T.[Customer_Engagement_Id])

WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 

SET 

        T.[Customer_Engagement_Context_Key]             =   S.[Customer_Engagement_Context_Key]                     
    ,T.[Engagement_Date_Key]                            =   S.[Engagement_Date_Key]             
    ,T.[Engagement_Time_Key]                            =   S.[Engagement_Time_Key]             
    ,T.[Contact_Key]                                    =   S.[Contact_Key]                     
    ,T.[Age_On_Engagement_Key]                          =   S.[Age_On_Engagement_Key]           
    ,T.[Programme_Interest_Context_Key]                 =   S.[Programme_Interest_Context_Key]      
    ,T.[Country_Of_Nationality_Key]                     =   S.[Country_Of_Nationality_Key]          
    ,T.[Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Key]              =   S.[Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Key]   
    ,T.[Country_Of_Residency_Key]                       =   S.[Country_Of_Residency_Key]            
    ,T.[Country_Lived_In_Key]                           =   S.[Country_Lived_In_Key]                
    ,T.[Event_Country_Key]                              =   S.[Event_Country_Key]                   
    ,T.[Programme_Type_Key]                             =   S.[Programme_Type_Key]                  
    ,T.[Programme_Key]                                  =   S.[Programme_Key]                       
    ,T.[Marketing_Campaign_Key]                         =   S.[Marketing_Campaign_Key]              
    ,T.[List_Load_Campaign_Key]                         =   S.[List_Load_Campaign_Key]              
    ,T.[Event_Campaign_Key]                             =   S.[Event_Campaign_Key]                  
    ,T.[Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Key]                 =   S.[Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Key]      
    ,T.[Score_Removed_Date_Key]                         =   S.[Score_Removed_Date_Key]              
    ,T.[Account_Key]                                    =   S.[Account_Key]                     
    ,T.[Programme_Interest_Score]                       =   S.[Programme_Interest_Score]            
    ,T.[Customer_Engagement_Score]                      =   S.[Customer_Engagement_Score]           
    ,T.[Customer_Engagement_Default_Score]              =   S.[Customer_Engagement_Default_Score]   
    ,T.[Multi_Campaign_Attribution_Flag]                =   S.[Multi_Campaign_Attribution_Flag] 
    ,T.[New_Contact_Flag]                               =   S.[New_Contact_Flag]                    
    ,T.[Customer_Engagement_Count]                      =   S.[Customer_Engagement_Count]
    ,T.[HashId]                                         =   S.[HashId]
    ,T.[Last_Updated_Date_Time]                         =   GETDATE()           
    ,T.[Entity_Record_Source]                           =   S.[Entity_Record_Source]                




WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 


INSERT ([Customer_Engagement_Id], [Customer_Engagement_Context_Key], [Engagement_Date_Key], [Engagement_Time_Key], [Contact_Key], [Age_On_Engagement_Key], [Programme_Interest_Context_Key], [Country_Of_Nationality_Key], [Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Key], [Country_Of_Residency_Key], [Country_Lived_In_Key], [Event_Country_Key], [Programme_Type_Key], [Programme_Key], [Marketing_Campaign_Key], [List_Load_Campaign_Key], [Event_Campaign_Key], [Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Key], [Score_Removed_Date_Key], [Account_Key], [Programme_Interest_Score], [Customer_Engagement_Score], [Customer_Engagement_Default_Score], [Multi_Campaign_Attribution_Flag], [New_Contact_Flag], [Customer_Engagement_Count], [HashId], [Last_Updated_Date_Time], [Entity_Record_Source])

VALUES

        (    S.[Customer_Engagement_Id]
            ,S.[Customer_Engagement_Context_Key]        
            ,S.[Engagement_Date_Key]                
            ,S.[Engagement_Time_Key]                
            ,S.[Contact_Key]                        
            ,S.[Age_On_Engagement_Key]                                              
            ,S.[Programme_Interest_Context_Key]     
            ,S.[Country_Of_Nationality_Key]         
            ,S.[Second_Country_Of_Nationality_Key]  
            ,S.[Country_Of_Residency_Key]           
            ,S.[Country_Lived_In_Key]               
            ,S.[Event_Country_Key]                  
            ,S.[Programme_Type_Key]                 
            ,S.[Programme_Key]                      
            ,S.[Marketing_Campaign_Key]             
            ,S.[List_Load_Campaign_Key]             
            ,S.[Event_Campaign_Key]                 
            ,S.[Trigger_Marketing_Campaign_Key]     
            ,S.[Score_Removed_Date_Key]             
            ,S.[Account_Key]                        
            ,S.[Programme_Interest_Score]           
            ,S.[Customer_Engagement_Score]          
            ,S.[Customer_Engagement_Default_Score]  
            ,S.[Multi_Campaign_Attribution_Flag]    
            ,S.[New_Contact_Flag]                   
            ,S.[Customer_Engagement_Count]
            ,S.[HashId]
            ,GETDATE()          
            ,S.[Entity_Record_Source]
        )
        ;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustEng_stg') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CustEng_stg;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustEng_delta') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CustEng_delta;
```

The problem is in the first INSERT INTO statement. Estimated execution plan is below:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1Z0hPp4B

I'm not sure if the JOINS are causing the issue.

EDIT:

The issue is in the joins, there are a few many-to-many relationships I hadn't catered for so I am going through and working out where the culprits are.
Thank you for all the answers, will post again when I get it fixed!

EDIT 2:

Updated query plan - those joins were very very wrong, but it's fixed now!
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1dV2OaVB

Comment: How many rows does that select statement return? The estimated plan has a absurdly high estimated row count for the insert.

Comment: It hasn't been able to execute in full so I'm not sure. I think there must be some many-to-many issue in one of the joins. Currently in the process of doing row counts when including a join one by one.

Comment: Running a convert on multiple join criteria is gonna hurt a lot, and running a seemingly large concatenation of fields into a hash on top of it? yeesh.

Comment: Looks like the queries from my BI team. I had to limit tempdb files to a max size to "fix" it.

Comment: 1. tempdb can be tweaked.  see  https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/correctly-adding-data-files-tempdb/  as ONE introduction to that.         2.  try EXPLICITLY declaring your #temp table instead of the "SELECT INTO".    example CREATE TABLE #myTempTable ( myint int not null )

Comment: Well, the plan shows Estimated Number of Rows 6.56525E+15 Estimated Row Size 9 B. It is a lot of rows and bytes. Way more than 32GB.

Comment: The estimated plan is saying 6.525E+15 rows. You need to go back to the beginning here and figure out what you are trying to do. Also find a way to filter your initial query so you don't insert everything into a temp table and then insert some of that data into another temp table that you are going to use.

Comment: Right? The first 2 join tables have an estimated 3.4m records in it and you're outer joining another 20 (!) tables in. Also it doesn't appear you have any indexes, or they are unused.

Comment: Why insert into a temp to begin with? What are you doing with it afterwards, if you *could* get it to work?

Comment: Have edited now - issue is many-to-many joins. Thanks for all comments.

Comment: @MattLakin Do you mind me help you post the answer? Or you can post the answer and mark it by yourself. Then others can reference from you.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having was in the JOINs criteria, some of the 'ON' matches were creating many-to-many joins which created a large amount of duplicate rows, as can be seen in the estimated rows in the first execution plan.

I fixed the issue by running COUNT() queries against the base table and then comparing the result to a COUNT() when subsequently adding a JOIN, e.g:

1. Take base count

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)

   FROM   [Integration].[Customer_Engagement] ce
```

2. Take count including the first JOIN

```
   SELECT COUNT(*)

   FROM   [Integration].[Customer_Engagement] ce

   LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reporting].[Dim_Contact] c
   ON ce.[LBS_Number] = c.[LBS_Number]
   AND CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar,[Engagement_Date])) BETWEEN c.[Row_Effective_Date] 
   AND c.[Row_Expiry_Date]
```

3. Compare Counts between (1) and (2). If the count is higher in (2), then there is an issue with the join!
4. Continue for rest of the joins, noting where counts increase

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations that Matt Lakin's  problem is fixed now. Thanks for all the helps in comment.

1. The issue is many-to-many joins.
2. Matt Lakin has fixed it now, to see the Updated query plan:
   https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1dV2OaVB

I help Matt Lakin post this as answer and hope this can be beneficial to other community members.